# Installing CMU fonts on NixOS

Tags: fonts, latex, nixos, nix

I have figured out that I need [CMU fonts](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern) to be able to typeset Russian text with XeLaTeX.  Under NixOS there is [`cm-unicode`](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#cm-unicode) package for it, I have installed it with

```
nix-env -iA nixos.cm_unicode
```

but XeLaTeX still cannot find it.  A LaTeX file that I can compile with XeLaTeX on Ubuntu does not compile with XeLaTeX on NixOS, and I get an error that the CMU font that I indicated was not found.

I've learned that I could list all fonts installed on the system with [`fc-list`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-list), so I tried running `fc-list | grep -i cmu`, `fc-list | grep -i com`, `fc-list | grep -i unic`, but got no results.

**How can I get this font installed?**  This is for NixOS 17.09.

---

By the way, I have already had to manually install Latin Modern font: it was initially not available for selection in XeLaTeX, but after I installed `lmodern` package with `nix-env -i`, it works fine.

I have just tested this again: uninstalling `lmodern` with `nix-env -e` removes Latin Modern from the results of `fc-list` and from `font-manager`, and installing with `nix-env -i` restores it.  The same does not work the same with `cm_unicode`.

---

I have a possibly related question, so I'll put it here.  (If it turns out that it is not related, I would appreciate a short comment or explanation.)

I wanted to define my TeX Live environment with all its dependencies in my `.nixpkgs/config.nix`, so I did

```nix
# .nixpkgs/config.nix
{ # ...
  packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    myTexLive = pkgs.texlive.combine {
      inherit (pkgs.texlive) scheme-basic
                             collection-bibtexextra
                             collection-fontsrecommended
                             collection-genericrecommended
                             collection-langcyrillic
                             collection-langfrench
                             collection-latex
                             collection-latexextra
                             collection-latexrecommended
                             collection-mathextra
                             collection-xetex
                             cm-unicode  # from `collection-fontsextra`
                             latexmk
                             lm       # from `collection-fontsrecommended`
                             lm-math  # from `collection-fontsrecommended`
                             texdoc;
    };
}
```

I was hoping that having `lm` and `cm-unicode` TeX Live packages would be enough to have the Latin Modern and CMU fonts install, but it did not work.

Is there any way to declare the necessary fonts as dependencies of `myTexLive`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On NixOS fonts cannot be installed via `nix-env` because for fonts to be found  a database of sorts needs to be created. That requires side-effects, yet Nix packages are pure functions. In general, you can think of side-effecting code as being handled by `nixos-rebuild`; hence you'll need to use `configuration.nix`:

```
fonts.fonts = [ pkgs.cm_unicode ];
```

You can watch my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKCSsmDylWM&t=3s) on NixOS fonts for a demonstration. Pardon my robot-voice.

For Latex-specific info, see https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-language-texlive

Comment: Thanks, i will try and report back.  However, i remember that after installing TeXLive, there were no Latin Modern either, and i installed it with `nix-env -iA nixos.lmodern`.  Also, Latin Modern shows up in the results of `fc-list`.  Can you explain this difference?  Should i also reinstall `lmodern` via `configuration.nix`?

Comment: Adding `cm_super` to `fonts.fonts` in `configuration.nix` worked indeed.  Can you comment on the difference between `lmodern` and `cm_unicode`?  (I edited the question.)  If `lmodern` works when installed with `nix-env`, should i still declare it in `configuration.nix` to avoid problems?  Is it possible to install a font for just one user?

Comment: In short: I don't know. You can check what depends on `lmodern` by first identifying the store path (/nix/store/blah-lmodern-blah) and then feeding it into `nix-store -q --referrers PATH`. As far as I know, the font cache is build by the NixOS font module and it operates system-wide; So no, font's are system, not user specific. For instance, if you follow the link `/etc/fonts` you'll see it results in a single path; there's no Nix profile involved. I recommend using `configuration.nix` for all fonts.

Comment: Can you include this additional info into your answer, please?